# Template inheritance in odoo 13/14

Tags: xml, templates, inheritance, odoo, qweb

I was struggling to get this right. I have a template which has bunch of css and js files. I want to extend the template and add one more file.

template1

```
<template id="template1_assets_frontend" name="SP Registration Full Form Assets Frontend" >     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/static/src/js/test1.js" />
</template>
```

Now I wan to create template2 which extend template1 and adds one more js file.
I have used `inherit_id` like this:

```
<template id="template2_assets_frontend" name="SP Registration Full Form Assets Frontend" inherit_id="template1">
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/static/src/js/test2.js" />
    </xpath>
</template>
```

But the problem with this is, it is modifying template1 also. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 1-2 hours on this I came to know that there is an attribute `primary="True"` to achieve this which is hidden here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/data.html#template.

So the extended template will be like this:

````
<template id="template2_assets_frontend" name="SP Registration Full Form Assets Frontend" inherit_id="template1" primary="True">
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/static/src/js/test2.js" />
    </xpath>
</template> ```
````